# How to map into get-only target child object?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a source and a destination type similar to these.

```
public class Source {
    public int A { get; set; }
    public SourceChild Child { get; } = new SourceChild ();
}

public class SourceChild {
    public int B { get; set; }
}

public class Destination {
    public int A { get; set; }
    public DestinationChild Child { get; } = new DestinationChild();
}

public class DestinationChild {
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

I'm creating my mapping in a profile in a trivial way without any additional configuration.

```
...
this.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
this.CreateMap<SourceChild, DestinationChild>();
...
```

When I try to map, I find that in the result `Destination` object the `Child` property is an *empty* instance of `DestinationChild` having `B` equal to zero.

```
var source = new Source() {
    A = 1,
    Child = {
        B = 2
    }
};

var destination = mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source);
```

I would expect that `destination.Child.B` equals to `2`.

I've tried adding the `UseDestinationValue` configuration for the destination member `Child`, but did not change anything.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I wasn't expect this but seems like it will work when having an explicit `MapFrom` in the mapping configuration like this.

```
...
this.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(e => e.Child, o => o.MapFrom(e => e.Child));
this.CreateMap<SourceChild, DestinationChild>();
...
```

So my next question is why is this needed? Wouldn't it be expected as the default behavior by convention?

**UPDATE 2**

Just to dig even further down, if I have a get-only child `List<T>` property in the root object, it won't map either unless I add the explicit `MapFrom`. However, if I have a get-only child `List<T>` property inside the get-only `DestinationChild`, then it will get populated from soruce just fine. I feel like there is some inconsistent behavior here.

Comment: Yes, but that's just history. You need the `MapFrom`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thank you for your comment. Could you please clarify a bit more what exactly are you ansering to by saying "yes", and also what you mean by "history"? Would be great if you had time to put together an answer with some links to the corresponding docs (which I could not find yet).

Comment: You should be able to find in the AM repo the issue where this was discussed.